# How do I create a database for an existing user in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I want to create a database for a particular (existing) user in MySQL. How do I do that ?

What i tried -

```
CREATE USER 'myuser' @'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
CREATE DATABASE myuser.myDatabase;
```

The second line is wrong. I cannot find the proper syntax.

Please tell me my mistake.

Comment: Please post an example of code that you've tried, or at least an explanation of what you have thought about. See: whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: @Erty - ok, edited my question accordingly.

Comment: What do you mean "database for a particular (existing) user"?

Comment: This question and answer should probably be migrated to dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

when i create a user named test and create a db named test in phpmyadmin
it runs:

```
CREATE USER 'test'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY  '***';

GRANT USAGE ON * . * TO  'test'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY  '***' WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0 ;

CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS  `test` ;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON  `test` . * TO  'test'@'localhost';
```

this may help you.

Comment: and you'll probably omit first line because you already have the user.

Comment: does the username have to be same as database name ?

Comment: in your own query(line1) you created database "test"

Comment: Please refer to the last line - 

    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON  `test` . * TO  'test'@'localhost';

Does the .* part mean that user gets all privileges for all tables of database ?

Answer (score 3):

I tried this code. It seems to be ok.

```
CREATE USER 'myuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
CREATE DATABASE mydb;

GRANT ALL 
ON mydb.*
TO myuser;
```